# When does $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-8)^nx^n $ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to determine when the following series converges:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-8)^nx^n $$

When approaching these problems, do I simply just have to guess-and-check with cases or is there a better way to determine convergence of a series?

I would assume I am looking for a value of $x$ such that: $(-8)^nx^n$ > $(-8)^{n+1}x^{n+1}$

So I'm guessing this convergence would occur when $x<1$. Is this correct? Any guidance about how I should approach this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As a quick note, $-1<1$, and the series doesn't converge for $x=-1$.

Comment: $-\frac 18 < x < \frac 18?$

Comment: @abel How did you calculate that?

Comment: you have a geometric series with the common ratio $-8x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to make a comment, so I'll write it as an answer:

This is a power series. There are two ways main ways to go about finding the convergence of power series. One way is to use the Ratio Test. The other way is to use the Root Test.

In the Ratio Test

$L =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left| \frac { { a }_{ n+1 } }{ { a }_{ n } }  \right|  } $.

In the power series you have given, this becomes

$L =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left| \frac { (-8)^{n+1}x^{n+1} }{ (-8)^nx^n }  \right|  }$

Simplifying this, we get

$L = 8\left|x\right|$. 
From the ratio test, we know that this converges only if $L<1$. From this, we can see that the power series only converges for $-\frac{1}{8} < x < \frac{1}{8}$.

The root test can be used in the same way to determine this too.

Comment: What of the case $L=1$?
cfr this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) and this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)

Comment: I did not add this in my solution (sorry!), but you should test the boundary cases to determine convergence at the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a geometric series, with common ratio $r = -8x$ we know that a geometric series converges when $-1<r<1$ which gives us $-1<-8x<1$ and by dividing all terms by $-8$ we get $\frac{1}{8}>x>\frac{-1}{8}$

Answer (score 1):

If you have a power series $\sum_\limits{n=1}^ {\infty}a_nx^n$, then its radius of convergence is given by the formula
\begin{equation}
R = \frac{1}{\limsup_\limits{n\to \infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}.
\end{equation}
And this power series converges for all $x$ with $|x|<R$. This formula will give you that $\sum_\limits{n=1}^ {\infty}(-8)^nx^n$ converges for all $x$ with $|x|<\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: For completion, you may also add that cases $x=\pm\frac{1}{8}$ must be checked separately.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It is clear that for both $x=\pm\frac{1}{8}$ it is not convergent. The series becomes $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$, which is not convergent.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-8x)^n$$
For geometric series, the $|r|<1$, so 
$$|-8x|<1$$
hence

$$|x|<1/8$$